# Use jq to remove the last three elements of an array

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm trying to use `jq` to get an array from a json object and I need to remove the last three elements of this array. So this is what I did so far:

```
echo '{ "tags": [ "2.9.7", "2.9.8", "2.9.9", "2.9.10", "2.9.11", "2.9.12" ]}' | jq -r '.tags | sort[:3][]'
```

gives me `2.9.10 2.9.11 2.9.12`, but need it the other way round. These values should be removed, so the result should be:

```
2.9.7 2.9.8 2.9.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the index counter at the third-last element `[-3`, and go until the end `:]`:

```bash
… | jq -r '.tags | sort[-3:][]'
```

```
2.9.7
2.9.8
2.9.9
```

Watch out, however, as you are sorting strings here, where `2.9.12` will be sorted before `2.9.7`. If you want to sort the array by version numbers (structured as seen), split them at the dot into an array, convert the items into numbers, and sort by that:

```bash
… | jq -r '.tags | sort_by(split(".") | map(tonumber))[:3][]'
```

```
2.9.7
2.9.8
2.9.9
```